# Apache SOLR - suggester leaves out hyphens and square brackets in suggestions

Tags: solr

Using SOLR 7.1.3, I'm trying to implement a suggester.
The basic suggestions work, but I have special terms in my index that look like this:

```
[999-99-9]
```

Now, when I run the suggester using

```
q=myfield:[999-9*
```

I do get a suggestions, but without the hyphens and square brackets.

```
sugggestions:[{ "term":"999 99 9" ...}]
```

My expectation would be:

```
sugggestions:[{ "term":"[999-99-9]" ...}]
```

How do I tell SOLR to include the square-brackets and hyphens?

Here's my suggester:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FreeTextLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">fulltext</str>
      <str name="ngrams">3</str>
      <float name="threshold">0.004</float>
      <str name="highlight">false</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
      <str name="storeDir">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="separator"> </str>
      <str name="suggestFreeTextAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

I also tried this (which doesn't return any results):

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">infixSuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">fulltext</str>
    <str name="payloadField">fulltext</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

[Edit] here's my fieldType definition:

```
<fieldType name="myField" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="'"
replacement="" replace="all" />

      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="'"
replacement="" replace="all" />

     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: What is the definition of your field? IIRC the FreeTextLookupFactory uses the generated tokens for the field to generate suggestions, and those will be preprocessed depending on your field definition.

Comment: I added the fieldType definition to my question. As I read, the KeywordTokenizerFactory should work? I tried it with «string» and «text_general» als well.

Comment: But you're giving `suggestFreeTextAnalyzerFieldType` as `text_general` - this field will be tokenized in a different way than the field type you've given.

Comment: When I use the same (myField) I get nothing back

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out.

**schema.xml**

```
    <fieldType name="myField" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

<field name="TheField" type="myField" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**solrconfig.xml:**

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
      <str name="suggest.dictionary">Suggester</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">Suggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FreeTextLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">TheField</str>
    <str name="storeDir">casSuggester</str>
    <str name="suggestFreeTextAnalyzerFieldType">myField</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

It still doesn't return the square brackets, but the hyphens are there.